# Have I fundamentally misunderstood how PHP/C-like programming languages work?

Tags: php

Take a look at this code:

```
if ($the_string = a_function_call('someid123') && $another_string = another_function_call('someid123'))
{
    // $the_string and $another_string are now both expected to be the values returned from their respective functions, and this block of code is expected to be run if both of them are not "falsey".
}
```

However...

```
if ($the_string = a_function_call('someid123') && $another_string = another_function_call('someid123'))
{
    // $the_string is now actually a boolean true. Not sure about $another_string.
}
```

Is this a weird bug? Or the intended behaviour? I've always thought that it was like the first scenario, and I've always coded by that assumption.

Comment: The `&&` operator *will* return true or false (boolean).

Comment: Couldn't get you, they both look the same

Comment: what is your intent? to test return value of `a_function_call`? if you want the return value, wrap it in parenthesis

Comment: @Viney The difference is the comment, not the code.

Answer (score 0):

`&&` has higher precedence than `=`. So your code is being parsed as if you'd written

```
if ($the_string = (a_function_call('someid123') && ($another_string = another_function_call('someid123'))))
```

This performs the following steps:

1. Calls `a_function_call()`
2. If that returns a truthy value, it calls `another_function_call()` and assigns the result to `$another_string()`.
3. Assigns the truth value of the `&&` expression to `$the_string`
4. Tests that truth value in the `if` statement.

This precedence allows you to write code like:

```
$success = function_1() && function_2();
```

If `=` had higher precedence, that would set `$success` just from `function_1()`, not the combination.

Adding parentheses would solve the problem:

```
if (($the_string = a_function_call('someid123')) 
    && ($another_string = another_function_call('someid123')))
```

PHP also has `and` and `or` operators that are like `&&` and `||`, but they have lower precedence than assignment; they exist to address this issue. You often see them used in code like this:

```
$variable = some_function(...) or die("some_function didn't work");
```

So simply replacing `&&` with `and` would also solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The key is the operator precedence.
The expression is evaluated as follow (pay attention to the parentheses):

```
if ($the_string = (a_function_call('someid123') && $another_string = another_function_call('someid123')))
```

`$another_string` takes the value from `another_function_call()` than is checked against `a_function_call()` return value through an AND operator.

Add the correct parentheses as follow to get the expected result:

```
if (($the_string = a_function_call('someid123')) && ($another_string = another_function_call('someid123')))
```

Please check the [php operators precedence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).